# Make SumatraPDF 3.0 remember position when recompiling PDFTexify from WinEDT 8.0

Tags: latex, miktex, pdftex

I have been writing my Thesis using WinEDT 8.0, MikTex 2.9, Sumatra PDF 2.4 (updated today to 3.0). PDF inverse search works, which means Sumatra and WinEDT are communicating. However, I used to be able to recompile my master *.tex file in PDFTexify and SumatraPDF remembers the position it was in, before recompiling, at some point it no longer remembers, instead it jumps to the beginning of the document, forcing me to scoll down manually. It's a bit frustrating. **Does anyone know the solution?**

I have updated Sumatra to 3.0 today from 2.4, no change

I have followed this guide here to the letter: http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/synchronizing-winedt-and-pdf-files/
No change

If it helps, My master tex files calls the chapter files with includeonly commands.